# programatically turn on/off gps in android versions 4.x & onwards

Tags: android

The below code works well in android versions 2.x.x. It successfully turns on gps in devices. But the problem is it doesn't work on android versions 4.x onwards.

**I am looking to turn on gps programatically in versions 4.x onwards. Any help or solution ?**

```
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        Utility.print("provider string " + provider);
        if (!provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is disabled
            Utility.print("gps is disabled now enabled");
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            sendBroadcast(poke);
            Utility.print("gps is disabled now enabled 1");
        } else {
            Utility.print("gps is already enabled");
        }
```

Comment: I've seen a lot of apps direct the user to the GPS settings screen rather than setting it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Third party apps should not be able to change protected system settings. I imagine this is a bug that was fixed for android 4.0 - possibly this one:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7890

Answer (score 0):

from the code:

```
 <receiver android:name=".widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider" android:label="@string/gadget_title">
```

and above the android 4.0 become to this:

```
 <receiver android:name=".widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"
            android:label="@string/gadget_title"
            android:exported="false"
            android:enabled="@bool/has_powercontrol_widget">
```

added the `android:exported="false"`

> Whether or not the content provider can be used by components of other
>   applications — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not. If "false",
>   the provider is available only to components of the same application
>   or applications with the same user ID. The default value is "true".

so, your application dont have some uid and components name with the setting app, so it didn't work .